# Converting Grey image to blue and red image

Tags: python, opencv

I was wondering how to take a greyscale image and turn the dark pixels to red and the white pixels to blue? All the other pixels that look grey (not completely black or white) should be a transition from red to blue.

I tried the following by taking the greyscale image, converting it to RGB, and then tried to remove the green channel. But the image just looks pinkish:

```
im = cv2.imread('grey_img.jpg')
im[:,:,1] = 0
```

So how could I make the grey image into a blue to red image?

Answer (score 4):

I came to some math things, and they're elegant:

```
img = cv2.imread('images/lena.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# find some percentiles for grayscale range of src image
percentiles = np.percentile(img, [0, 25, 75, 100])

# define the same count of values to further interpolation
targets = np.geomspace(10, 255, 4)

# use interpolation from percentiles to targets for blue and red
b = np.interp(img, percentiles, targets).astype(np.uint8)
g = np.zeros_like(img)
r = np.interp(img, percentiles, targets[::-1]).astype(np.uint8)

# merge channels to BGR image
result = cv2.merge([b, g, r])
```

Result:

[image: logspace interpolation result]

You can adjust brightness by changing percentiles or target space points

Answer (score 2):

Removing a colorband will not accomplish what you've described because you're trying to colorize an image, not de-color it.  A pixel level function to decide what to do with each pixel is a good way to solve this.

[image]

```
from PIL import Image

def pixop_redblue(pixel):
    pixel, alpha = pixel[:3], pixel[3:]
    grey = sum(pixel) // len(pixel)
    redvalue = 255 - grey  # "darkness"
    bluevalue = grey  # "brightness"
    return (redvalue, 0, bluevalue) + alpha


img = Image.open('trees.jpg')
img2 = img.copy()
img2.putdata([pixop_redblue(pixel) for pixel in img.getdata()])
img2.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I meant to say a greyscale image. Not a pure white and pure black image. I will convert the image I have into greyscale and I suppose I could use the same concept as you mentioned, but instead of a threshold, I will have it quantified by the intensity of the greyscale pixel. That might give me the transitions instead of just a binary blue or red.

Comment: Yes, the strategy is the same.  You will simply want to use the grey value to determine the "lightness" and "darkness" of the pixel for the blue and red values, respectively.  I updated my function to do this for you.  This function doesn't care if the original image is grey or colored.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to apply a gradient color to a grayscale image using Python/OpenCV.

```
 - Load the grayscale image

 - Convert it to 3 equal channels (only if image is 1 channel grayscale already)

 - Create a 1 pixel red image

 - Create a 1 pixel blue image

 - Concatenate the two

 - Resize linearly to 256 pixels as a Lookup Table (LUT)

 - Apply the LUT

 - Save the result
```

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image as grayscale
img = cv2.imread('lena_gray.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# convert to 3 equal channels (only if img is already 1 channel grayscale)
img = cv2.merge((img, img, img))

# create 1 pixel red image
red = np.zeros((1, 1, 3), np.uint8)
red[:] = (0,0,255)

# create 1 pixel blue image
blue = np.zeros((1, 1, 3), np.uint8)
blue[:] = (255,0,0)

# append the two images
lut = np.concatenate((red, blue), axis=0)

# resize lut to 256 values
lut = cv2.resize(lut, (1,256), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

# apply lut
result = cv2.LUT(img, lut)

# save result
cv2.imwrite('lena_red_blue_lut_mapped.png', result)

# display result
cv2.imshow('RESULT', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]